# React rendering child components with passing props to child components

Tags: reactjs

So I have a workspace component, rendering child `<IndividualWorkspaceOverview />`,

```
{requested ? (
        allWorkspace.map((e) => (
          <IndividualWorkspaceOverview
            key={e.user}
            detail={e.q1}
            user={e.user}
          />
        ))
      ) : (
        <div></div>
      )}
```

and `<IndividualWorkspaceOverview />` returns

```
    <div>
      <button>{props.user}'s Workspace</button>
    </div>
  );
```

The issue comes when I want to implement where, when a user clicks on the button, it displays that user's workspace.

One solution I came up is, render only one `<IndividualWorkspaceOverview />`,pass the allWorkspace array to it , and set a if condition to either render buttons of a overview of workspaces, or a `<IndividualWorkspace />`  ,  set a handle click functions to those buttons and pass to each button a username as props ,when a button is clicked, the button will cause a re-render of `<IndividualWorkspaceOverview />` and display `<IndividualWorkspace />` associated with that buttons username.

I was wondering if there is a better way to implement this?

The solution I came up with.

```
  return (
    <div className="container-workspace">
      <h4>workspace</h4>

      {console.log(allWorkspace)}
      {requested ? (
        <div>
          <button onClick={handleClickBack}>Back To Questions</button>
          <button>Create my own workspace</button>
          <IndividualWorkspaceOverview allWorkspace={allWorkspace} />
        </div>
      ) : (
        <div>
          <button type="button" onClick={handleClick}>
            Q1
          </button>
          <button>Q2</button>
          <button>Q3</button>
          <button>Q4</button>
          <button>Q5</button>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
```

```
const IndividualWorkspaceOverview = (props) => {
  const [clicked, setClicked] = useState(false);
  const [viewOverview, setViewOverview] = useState(true);

  //contains the user workspace detail for rendering
  const [workspaceDetail, setWorkspaceDetail] = useState("");

  const handleClick = (detail) => [setWorkspaceDetail(detail)];

  return (
    <div>
      {viewOverview ? (
        props.allWorkspace.map((e) => (
          <button
            onClick={() => {
              setViewOverview(!viewOverview);
              handleClick(e.q1);
            }}
          >
            {e.user} 's Woskapce
          </button>
        ))
      ) : (
        <IndividualWorkspace detail={workspaceDetail} />
      )}
    </div>
  );
};
```

```
const IndividualWorkspace = (props) => {
  const [workspaceDetail, setWorkspaceDetail] = useState(props.detail);
  return (
    <div className="container-individual-workspace">
      <textarea
        value={workspaceDetail}
        onChange={(e) => setWorkspaceDetail(e.target.value)}
      ></textarea>
      <button type="button">Save</button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Where should the component render the user workspace relative to the button, and how exactly would be the markup? Does props.user contain that user's workspace?

Comment: @cesartalves So there is a if condition in `<IndividualWorkspaceOverview />`, it will either render buttons or a user's workspace. The workspace for now is just some text represented in textarea. No, the buttons have props.detail which contains workspace text, there is a click handler that modifies the workspaceDetail, which will be passed on to `<IndividualWorkspace />` durinig re render. 
I don't think my solution is the right way to do it, as my way of doing it, doesn't allow user to select different questions without a going back button.